# PHP: Truncate a string

Tags: php

```
$urlPath = "http://localhost:8000/img/mercedes-benz-a-class-image.png";
$imgUrlPath = "http://localhost:8000/img/";


$imageName = ltrim($urlPath, $imgUrlPath);
```

And I have `ercedes-benz-a-class-image.png` without first `m`.

```
$imageName = preg_replace($imgUrlPath, "", urlPath);
```

It's not work...

How do I get a line `mercedes-benz-a-class-image.png`?

Comment: `$imageName = str_replace($imgUrlPath, "", $urlPath);` I have `mercedes-benz-a-class-image.png`

Answer (score 0):

To get file name from path, You can simply use [`basename()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php)

```
$urlPath = "http://localhost:8000/img/mercedes-benz-a-class-image.png";
$imageName = basename($urlPath);
```

[Live Demo](https://eval.in/1028429)

And to get Directory name use [`dirname`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php)

```
$urlPath = "http://localhost:8000/img/mercedes-benz-a-class-image.png";
echo $dirName = dirname($urlPath);
```

[Live Demo](https://eval.in/1028447)

**Edit** : *from your comment*

You can't have following character in your file name

[image]

Comment: and if $urlPath would be `http://localhost:8000/img/mercedes-benz-a-cla/ss-image.png` we have `ss-image.png`, this is a nonuniversal method

Comment: @Zanetti : what you mean by `nonuniversal method` what you expect in this case ?

Comment: I think they expect "mercedes-benz-a-cla/ss-image.png", which is not what's been asked, to be fair.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca : you can't have `/` slash in any file name

Comment: @Zanetti : If you are talking about symbol `/` in your path so it's can't included in file name

Comment: @C2486 that's the point, it's a "ss-image.png" file inside a "mercedes-benz-a-cla" directory. They want to reduce it to "mercedes-benz-a-cla/ss-image.png" while your method would give just "ss-image.png"

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

```
$urlPath = "http://localhost:8000/img/mercedes-benz-a-class-image.png";
$imgUrlPath = "http://localhost:8000/img/";


$imageName = str_replace($imgUrlPath, "", $urlPath);
```

Involving regexes just messes things up for something this simple. From the documentation:

> If you don't need fancy replacing rules (like regular expressions), you should always use this function instead of `preg_replace()`.